# how to scan for keys whose values got updated since last SCAN

Tags: redis

I'd like to periodically scan thru a redis instance for keys that changed since the last scan. in between the scans i don't want to process the keys.

eg one key could get a thousand updates between scans. i care for the most recent value only when doing the next periodic scan.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way in Redis to achieve that (yet).

You could, for example, recode your app and add some sort of a way to track updates. For example, wherever you're calling `SET foo bar`, also call `ZADD updated <timestamp> foo`. Then, you can use the 'updated' Sorted Set to retrieve updated keys.

Alternatively, you can try using [RedisGears](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisgears) to automate the tracking part (for starters). Assuming that you have RedisGears running (i.e. `docker run -it -p 6379:6379 redislabs/redisgears`), you can do something like the following:

```
$ cat gear.py
def addToUpdatedZset(x):
    import time
    now = time.time()
    execute('ZADD', 'updated', now, x['key'])
    return x

GB().filter(lambda x: x['key'] != 'updated').foreach(addToUpdatedZset).register('*')

$ redis-cli RG.PYEXECUTE "$(cat gear.py)"
OK
$ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> KEYS *
(empty list or set)
127.0.0.1:6379> SET foo bar
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> KEYS *
1) "updated"
2) "foo"
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGE updated 0 -1 WITHSCORES
1) "foo"
2) "1559339877.1392548"
127.0.0.1:6379> SET baz qux
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> KEYS *
1) "updated"
2) "baz"
3) "foo"
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGE updated 0 -1 WITHSCORES
1) "foo"
2) "1559339877.1392548"
3) "baz"
4) "1559339911.5493586"
```